# How to test IntentService android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing, android-espresso, intentservice

How can I test an `IntentService` in android without using the deprecated `ServiceTestCase`?

From the documentation of the [ServiceTestCase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ServiceTestCase.html):

> This class was deprecated in API level 24.
>   Use ServiceTestRule instead. New tests should be written using the Android Testing Support Library.

But the [ServiceTestRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ServiceTestRule.html) documentation says it doesn't support `IntentService`s:

> Note: This rule doesn't support IntentService because it's automatically destroyed when onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent) finishes all outstanding commands. 
>   So there is no guarantee to establish a successful connection in a timely manner.

How am I supposed to test an `IntentService` then ?

Answer (score 5):

The [service testing page](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/integration-testing/service-testing.html) in the android documentation says (emphasis mine):

> Note: The ServiceTestRule class does not support testing of
>   IntentService objects. If you need to test a IntentService object, **you
>   should encapsulate the logic in a separate class and create a
>   corresponding unit test instead.**

So the official answer would seem to be "use a unit test instead."  However, ServiceTestCase being deprecated doesn't mean you can't continue to use it -- just that doing so is discouraged.  If using a deprecated interface is the only (or most efficient) way to accomplish your goal, then you should continue using it.